How do I cite my friend’s translation?
I dont speak Turkish, so I asked a Turkophone friend of mine to translate a page from a book so that I could use it in a paper. How would I go about citing this? Do I need to include his name?

A person who translates a text for you to use in your publication is not a source but a contributor and may be acknowledged in the author note.
The Chicago Manual of Style (CMOS) doesn't explain how it distinguishes different kinds of contributors, but the Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association does, and in quite some detail. It distinguishes "substantial" from "lesser" contributions:

Authorship is reserved for persons who make a substantial contribution to and who accept responsibility for a published work. Individuals should take authorship credit only for work they have performed or to which they have substantially contributed (APA Ethics Code Standard 8.12a, Publication Credit). Authorship encompasses, therefore, not only those who do the writing but also those who have made substantial scientific contributions to a study. Substantial professional contributions may include formulating the problem or hypothesis, structuring the experimental design, organizing and conducting the statistical analysis, or interpreting the results and findings. Those who so contribute are listed in the byline [i.e. a line of text, usually below the title of the article, listing the author(s)]. Lesser contributions, which do not constitute authorship, may be acknowledged in the author note (see Section 2.7; see also a taxonomy of authorship in the natural sciences called at CRediT). Lesser contributions may include such supportive functions as designing or building the apparatus, suggesting or advising about the analysis, collecting or entering the data, modifying or structuring a computer program, recruiting participants, and obtaining animals. Conducting routine observations or diagnoses for use in studies does not constitute authorship. Combinations of these (and other) tasks, however, may justify authorship.

Following APA, you would credit your translator in the author note on the title page of your manuscript. Here is an example title page with author note from the APA Stlye Blog:

The CMOS is mainly concerned with the publication of books and doesn't give much information on how to format manuscripts for scientific journal articles. In a book, according to the CMOS, non-authorial credits (such as illustrators) can be acknowledged on the copyright page or, if they require more space and greater prominence, in a special acknowledgements section in the front or back matter.
Kate L. Turabians A Manual for Writers of Research Papers, Theses, and Dissertations, which is based on the CMOS, expounds:

In a thesis or dissertation you may have a separate section of acknowledgments in which you thank mentors and colleagues or name the individuals or institutions that supported your research or provided special assistance (such as consultation on technical matters or aid in securing special equipment and source materials).

The acknowledgements are part of the front matter in Turabian's Manual and follow the list of tables and illustrations, immediately before the beginning of the text. Again, as in the CMOS, no explanation is given where to credit non-authorial contributors in a manuscript for a journal article.
If you write a paper that you want to submit to a journal, I would ask the publisher, how and where you should acknowledge your translator.

In text, as Divizna said, you'd mention the translator in parenthesis:

"..." (Çelebi, 1939; translated by Orhan Haşim).


Don't know exactly how you do this according to the Chicago Manual in particular, but in any case, the general standard is yes, you do have to make it clear where anything you say comes from, and that includes the source of any translation you're using. I'd imagine something like "[standard source citation, author, title, year etc.], translation XY, unpublished", or "[source citation], excerpt translated by XY". If you translated the excerpt yourself, you'd also have to make a note about it.
